# migrating the version of material-ui from v4 to v5, found problem with emotion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I had migrate my version of material-ui v4 to v5.0.0-alpha.32 and notice that have some new StyleEngineProvider in order to run the old engine (jss) in the new version. But whe i run yarn build, it generated an empty styled on the header:

[image: html-code]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that i upgrated only the @material-ui/core and forgot to upgrade the subpackages like @material-ui/styled and @material-ui/icons

Comment: Thanks for coming back and updating your question